# Could not resolve host: api-content.dropbox.com

Tags: php, dropbox-php

I am frequently facing this issue  Could not resolve host: api-content.dropbox.com 
While dropbox upload. I am facing this only some of shared hosting server. I contacted my hosting provider they said every thing fine. Can any one help what causing issue? I searched but not find solution.

NOTE :I am using drop box v1 API and also tried new URL content.dropboxapi.com same issue. Same server same time working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue I am trying to upload the large size file to Dropbox using chunk upload after upload starts the server went down in some period of the time. I found it through server error log.